# how to develop code for Nexus 5 in my computer locally?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have installed UbuntuTouch SDK but there is not hardware kit for Nexus 5. I want to develop application for Nexus 5. What options do i have?

Comment: If you wish to test your app in phone you can build a click package and install on your phone via the Terminal app or adb.

Comment: How I can build a click package? is that built by ubuntu-sdk? Because ubuntu-sdk does not have a platform kit for Nexus 5

Comment: try using some generic kit like i386 emulator

Comment: @promsky,  Thank you for the reply. Can a click package use some GSM library functions for a telephone call or SMS? If i develop such a code for an i386 emulator, can the executable  be moved to a real mobile phone?

Comment: No idea, mate! : (

Comment: You may join this team: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-phone and ask your question in their mailing list. Someone might be able to provide an answer.